# SQL server views Vs Inline TVF

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

If we create view vw_myView and inline function fn_myFunction with same select statement inside. Which is optimized?
Now next level question is If I put where condition will calling the view or function like below:

```
Select * from vw_myView where col1 = 'abc'
Select * from vw_myFunction() where col1 = 'abc'
```

how the where condition works here in case of execution plan?

which one is optimized?

Comment: Don't try to learn "absolute" performance rules and then rigidly stick to them. My advice - write the simplest code you can that does the job you need it to (so here, a view). Then *measure* the performance. Then *compare* the performance to your performance *goals*. If it meets those goals, great, the job is done, move onto the next job. If it doesn't, *then* start analysing *where* the performance issue is and address it.

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer USUALLY knows best, and will expand the embedded SQL query as part of the plan; that being said, inline tvf's can have issues with parameter sniffing (if you have parameters, which you don't in the above example).  For that reason, I tend to choose views over inline tvf's.

Comment: Of course, contrariwise, if you *do* have parameters then of course there's no choice - views cannot be parameterised.

Comment: if we have parameters then execution plan will be different? I mean to say If I pass a parameters to function to put that in where condition. If I use same where condition in select query of view. in that case execution plan will be same?

Comment: In the specific example that you provided, there will probably be no difference in the execution plan.  In a parameterized TVF, there is the possibility that the optimizer will choose an inaccurate plan if the parameter provided affects the distribution of data included.

Answer (score 0):

Both views and inline TVFs are simply inlined into the outer query plan as if you had pasted the text. The optimizer has zero special handling for this. Optimization proceeds on the inlined queries. There is *never* a perf difference between views and TVFs. Parameter sniffing affects the query as a whole.

Pushing around where filters is a trivial optimization that can be relied upon.

Comment: Can usually be relied on but not always http://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/t-sql-queries/the-problem-with-window-functions-and-views though the OP isn't parametrising the TVF anyway.

Comment: @MartinSmith that limitation does not seem to arise from the presence of a view. The same query with the view definition pasted into it would have resulted in the same limitation. When he "generalized" the query by factoring out a view he changed the location of the where predicate.

Comment: I am not concerned about parameters, I am concerned about the where condition, how the where condition behaves in case of execution plan. how the optimizer behaves in case of view and inline function.

Comment: The comment was in response to the line "Pushing around where filters is a trivial optimization that can be relied upon." if this was true changing the location of the where predicate wouldn't have made any difference.

Comment: @MartinSmith I understand now. I should refrain from making these general statements.